# Google Charts help required, for Demand & Supply chart with extra vertical line

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[See this link for chart type](http://mm.btc123.com/btcchina.php)

Actually, I want to create a demand & supply chart (with Google Charts API) this will be a simple Area chart with to area lines (one for demand & other for supply), but also I want to show a third line (not area only line) see the above link for example.

Any ideas how could I draw such Chart, I could only manage to draw without the Center line part.

Image :
[image: This is the example image]

Thanks

Comment: Here is a sketch of an idea: You could use a combo chart using 'area' and 'line' together, and then flip the orientation using 'orientation': 'vertical'.  The areas should be stacked (using isStacked: true) and then you have to add a column for the white fill area between the red and blue areas - you'll have to know the maximum size of the red and blue areas together.  You'll also need an extra red column with zero values just to draw a line for the red area.

Comment: @dlaliberte, you don't need to do that, you can actually make it work with a regular ComboChart.  The trick is in inputting the data into the line series.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @asgallant, ingeneous!. (My idea was merely devious.) This is probably a good reason keep allowing the continuous range values (on the domain axis) to be unsorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a ComboChart.  The trick is in creating the middle line - normally, you draw lines horizontally, using (x, y) coordinate pairs; to draw vertically, invert the pairs to (y, x), but you must keep them ordered by the x-value (otherwise the line will become messed up).  Here's some example code:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'demand');
    data.addColumn('number', 'supply');
    data.addColumn('number', 'other');
    data.addRows([
        [0, 100, null, null],
        [1, 95, null, null],
        [2, 93, null, null],
        [3, 84, null, null],
        [4, 79, null, null],
        [5, 70, null, null],
        [6, 63, null, null],
        [7, 52, null, null],
        [8, 47, null, null],
        [9, 38, null, null],
        [10, 34, null, null],
        [11, 31, null, null],
        [12, 29, null, null],
        [13, 22, null, null],
        [14, 19, null, null],
        [15, 17, null, null],
        [16, 11, null, null],
        [17, 9, null, null],
        [18, 5, null, null],
        [19, 2, null, null],
        [20, 0, 0, null],
        [21, 0, 0, null],
        [22, 0, 0, null],
        [23, null, 4, null],
        [24, null, 8, null],
        [25, null, 11, null],
        [26, null, 16, null],
        [27, null, 22, null],
        [28, null, 27, null],
        [29, null, 35, null],
        [30, null, 43, null],
        [31, null, 44, null],
        [32, null, 51, null],
        [33, null, 55, null],
        [34, null, 62, null],
        [35, null, 69, null],
        [36, null, 73, null],
        [37, null, 77, null],
        [38, null, 81, null],
        [39, null, 88, null],
        [40, null, 94, null],
        [41, null, 99, null],
        [42, null, 100, null],
        /* add the middle line series here
         * invert the normal (x, y) relationship that would draw the line horizontally
         * input as [y, null, null, x]
         * order the input by the x value, otherwise the line will be screwed up
         */
        [21, null, null, 0],
        [23, null, null, 5],
        [26, null, null, 10],
        [17, null, null, 15],
        [19, null, null, 20],
        [23, null, null, 25],
        [18, null, null, 30],
        [20, null, null, 35],
        [24, null, null, 40],
        [22, null, null, 45],
        [16, null, null, 50],
        [21, null, null, 55],
        [29, null, null, 60],
        [24, null, null, 65],
        [21, null, null, 70],
        [17, null, null, 75],
        [19, null, null, 80],
        [18, null, null, 85],
        [23, null, null, 90],
        [21, null, null, 95],
        [24, null, null, 100]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        series: {
            0: {
                // demand series
                type: 'area'
            },
            1: {
                // supply series
                type: 'area'
            },
            2: {
                // other series
                type: 'line'
            }
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/dfGth/

Comment: Great Thanks for such an easy example. I spent al lot time for this but couldn't. It's awsome.